# Highcharts add a legend for marker colors

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a line chart with a single data series. Now for certain points I have used different marker colors, and I wanted to add a legend for these marker colors. Is it possible to incorporate it in highcharts itself or should I make an external div?

Comment: A codepen or a small fiddle example will be useful to suggest. however seems like you need `names` in series. Take a look here if this might help : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional scatter series for the markers, for example:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        data: [1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, {
        name: 'marker1',
        data: [
            [3, 1]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'marker2',
        data: [
            [5, 6]
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lbf9cqnm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter